# HOWTO determine why Hybris extension will not load

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am working on setting up a Hybris B2B instance and when I look in HAC's Extensions the storefront has a red X, not a green checkmark.  I assume that means there is an error somewhere, where do I go to find the error?

Some background on what I have done:

1. extract Hybris 1811
2. install -r b2b_acc_plus
3. ant clean all
4. ant modulegen and selected **accelerator**...
5. ant clean all
6. ant initialize
7. hybrisserver.sh

At that point the server is running, I can get to the HAC, but cannot get to the storefront.  I am guessing I might be missing a step, too, but all the same, there are other extensions that have the red X so I would like to understand how to explore the reason why.

Comment: Past the console log here, which you can see while you are trying to access the storefront. In the case of Error "Cannot find CMSSite associated with current URL", refer [cannot-find-cmssite-associated-with-URL-hybris](https://www.helphybris.com/2018/07/cannot-find-cmssite-associated-with-URL-hybris.html)

Answer (score 2):

- Red Cross against storefront extension in Hybris Admon Console is to depict that its not a backoffice/hmc extension.
- You would also notice a green check to depict its a core module.
- Also in front of storefront extension, you willl not the webroot URL. Normally its default value is /yacceleratorstorefront unless one changed it.

You should be able to access storefront using 
`http://localhost:9001/yacceleratorstorefront?site=apparel-uk`

You can change site param in URL to access any of the configured websites.

**Example**

...?site=electronics

...?site=apparel-de

**Alternatively**, you can add URL mapping in host file.

Make the following entry in your hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 apparel-uk.local apparel-de.local electronics.local
```

Once your hybris server is running, you can access any of the following URLs:

```
http://electronics.local:9001/yacceleratorstorefront/
http://apparel-uk.local:9001/yacceleratorstorefront/
http://apparel-de.local:9001/yacceleratorstorefront/
```

Thanks

Comment: For the sake of completeness, if you are installing b2b_acc_plus like OP said he does, then the sample storefront would be 'powertoolsstore', so the url would look like: http://localhost:9001/yb2bacceleratorstorefront?site=powertools or http://powertools.local:9001/yb2bacceleratorstorefront/ ( https://help.sap.com/viewer/4c33bf189ab9409e84e589295c36d96e/1905/en-US/8ab6a84e86691014b935a582ca5ef6fc.html )

Comment: vote up for @merterpam. Thanks for completing it altogether.